# Plotting the occurrence of an item per date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this kind of data:

```
dat
     date shop_id
1 2013-01       1
2 2013-02       2
3 2013-02       2
4 2013-02       2
5 2013-02       1
6 2013-03       3
7 2013-04       1
```

`shop_id` stands for a specific shop and `year_month` stands for the date. If a shop is listed at a specific date it means that it´s open, if not it´s closed (i.e. in Janury 2013/2013-01 shop 1 was open but not shop 2 and 3, in March 2013/2013-03 shop 3 was open but not shop 1 and 2). Since the data is about sales of a specific product, a shop can occur more than once per date. I want to plot the data. 
It should look like the plot below: On the y-axis should be the date, on the x-axis should be the shop_id and fill should be if the shop is open (shop_id occurs together with a specific date) or not.

```
  dput(dat)
    structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2013-01", 
"2013-02", "2013-03", "2013-04"), class = "factor"), shop_id = c(1, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

[image]

Comment: Your date column seems to only include a month, is this correct?

Comment: The date includes the year and the month. I want to consider both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(shop_id) %>%
  mutate(
    date = ymd(paste0(date, "-01")),
    start = min(date),
    end = max(date) %>% ceiling_date(unit = "month") # as Julian_Hn suggested
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(shop_id))) +
  geom_linerange(aes(
      ymin = start,
      ymax = end
    ),
    size = 40 # bar width
  )
```

#### Second proposition:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  nest() %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(ypos = row_number()) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = shop_id - .25,
    xmax = shop_id + .25,
    ymin = ypos - .5,
    ymax = ypos + .5
  ))
```

Comment: Nice solution. I would probably add a `ceiling_date` to your end value, so that it catches the whole month, if only one entry is available. So `end = ceiling_date(max(date),unit="month",change_on_boundary = T)`.

Comment: @Paweł Chabros It´s nice but not complete. As you can see from the data, shop 1 was open between  2013-01  and 2013-02 and in 2013-04 but not in 2013-03. So there must be a gap in the chart between  2013-03 and 2013-04. I think it has to do with the `min` and `max` argument.

Comment: @Banjo I've added second solution. Please check it.